# using sed for replacing strings with "/"

Tags: sed

need to replace < network> with a "192.168.61.0/24" but i am not able to do it with sed,

tried

```
 sed -i s/"< network>"/"192.168.61.0/24"/g file.sh
```

but this is not working

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Use another separator, i.e `#`

`sed -i s#"< network>"#"192.168.61.0/24"#g file.sh`

Or escape `/`

`sed -i s/"< network>"#"192.168.61.0\/24"/g file.sh`